# Angular ng-model values not registered on submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I know the title is kind of ambiguous but here is the issue: I have 2 input fields in a form that look like this:

```
<form name="modifyApp" class="form-signin" ng-submit="modify(val)">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="val.name" id="appName">
   <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="val.number" id="number" min="0" max="65535">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I load the page I populate those two with some values from inside the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('modifyAppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    function setFields(appName, appNumber){
        document.getElementById("appName").value = appName
        document.getElementById("number").value = appNumber
    }

    $scope.modify= function(val){
        console.log(val)
    }
}])
```

The problem is when I press the *Submit* button. The values won't get registered unless I change them. For example, if I  press the *Submit* button nothing gets printed, but if I change the number or the name, it gets printed.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the input fields not via AngularJS?

Comment: If you are already using ng-model, why are you trying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you can simply initialize the val object like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('modifyAppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.val = {
    name: '',
    number: 0
  };

  function setFields(appName, appNumber) {
    $scope.val.name = appName;
    $scope.val.number = appNumber;
  }

  $scope.modify = function(val) {
    console.log(val);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: That was so easy, thank you for that answer! What if I have two radio buttons and I want to check one of them when I use the _setFields_ function. How do I do that? How do I initialize one of the radio buttons in _$scope.val_?

Comment: You're welcome.  You'd just bind the radio buttons to a $scope variable using ng-model.  Then you can evaluate the $scope variable in setFields()

Comment: Wow it's so easy! Thanks a bunch! I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('modifyAppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.val = {
        name = 'My app name',
        number = '1'
    };

    function setFields(appName, appNumber){
        $scope.val.name = appName;
        $scope.val.number = appNumber;
    }

    $scope.modify= function(){
        console.log($scope.val);
    }
}])
```

You don't need to directly modify the DOM values in Angular. All your $scope variables are available in your template.

Answer (score 0):

why not just have the following as the first line in your form

```
<form name="modifyApp" class="form-signin" ng-submit="modify()">
```

and then your controller can look like this

```
$scope.val = {
  name: '',
  number:0//some default values
}
$scope.modify= function(){
    console.log($scope.val)
}
```